# Sending POST from HTML

Tags: html, url, post

I have an API at

`http://example.com/createclass`

In order to create a database entry I need the URL to be

`http://example.com/createclass/:classid/:classname/:someotherid`

How do I manipulate the URL string from my html page (This page takes input from the user)?

I do not want to send the body as a JSON. I know how to do that by serializing the form data into JSON and then sending it. I want to send the POST request to the following URL format:

`http://example.com/createclass/200/blah/ksjdf32ebr21`